# MF Notepad conversion

Tags: flash, notepad

Someone assign me a task to type some document in MF Notepad software (Adobe flash player MF Notepad). After typing I have to save that document. I can see that file but it does not have extension.

Issue is that software does not allow paste feature so I have to type the words, it is time consuming process.

So if I can know that in which extension MF Notepad save the file then if any software available in market which can directly convert word to that Mf notepad extension then it will fast for me.

According to my view I should convert in flash file but when I convert Word to Flash using other software and try to import/load that into MF Notepad it show me garbage like character (like box...)